# Логирование в приложениях ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, логирование

Кто какие способы использует для логирования web-приложений?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [AppendToLog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524861.aspx)